# dbt deps fails -> the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: visual-studio-code, dbt

I've ran "dbt deps" on Windows in VSCode and it runs successfully.
After I tried again with another package included, but it failed with the following;
"[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'dbt_packages\dbtvault-0.7.9'"
I've checked and the folder has some contents marked as "Read-Only", every time I change the folder to be non-read-only it changes back.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: `dbt deps` doesn't appear to me to have great handling for installing dependencies in sequential order and my intuition is that it attempts to install in parallel based on the threads given to run. I usually just run `dbt deps` two or three times and it catches everything up. I have *not* seen this error on dbtCloud though so my experience is that this is a local / cli only issue but not confirmed.

Comment: Thanks for this - so  far the only solution I have found is to copy the folder to a new location and change that to unmark read only then open the project from that location.
I get the feeling it may be the imaging software our company use for backups that is causing it.

Comment: Is your dbt project folder within any kind of restrictive directory (AppData, ProgramData, etc.)? Is it on a shared or network drive?
Agreed that there's something else interacting with this. Never experienced what you're referring to across 10+ dbt projects / installation all on windows platforms.

Comment: No - I've had it on a Network drive (which I know is imaged every day) and also on my local C drive (our local drives don't get backed up), although that c drive is on a VM and it's likely that gets backed up too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue using VS Code and tried to identify the process that was using the file/folder and prevent it from being accessed  (you can check this article https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows-10/). It turns out that it was actually VS Code (code.exe) doing this so as a turn around I closed VS Code and ran dbt deps from within the Git bash app and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue with `dbt deps` when running in the VSCode terminal. I was able to bypass it by closing VSCode and running the command in the Anaconda Powershell.

Don't really know what it causes it. This only happens in my working machine, and I only have user rights. My colleagues that have admins rights don't seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by opening the windows task management and stopping all of the Python.exe process. Of course this was the only process I was running so be aware if your're running something else or it will fail.