# dbt deps - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'dbt_packages\\dbt-expectations-0.5.1\\integration_tests'

Tags: dbt

I last used dbt several months ago.  Returning to it, I had to update from version 0.21.1 to 1.1.0 to match my team's project.  I've run dbt clean, then dbt deps always returns this error: [The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'dbt_packages\dbt-expectations-0.5.1\integration_tests'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIWBE.png)

I see two packages after it errors:  dbt_expectations & dbt-expectations-0.5.1 - I'm not sure what the latter package is about since it doesn't exist on my teammates machines.

These are all my packages which match my teammates:

- package: calogica/dbt_date
  version: 0.5.1
- package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
  version: 0.8.0
- package: dbt-labs/codegen
  version: 0.5.0
- package: calogica/dbt_expectations
  version: 0.5.1

There's nothing else using the mentioned file before executing dbt deps & I've restarted to ensure there wasn't anything hung up.  I don't see anything helpful in the logs:

> 14:28:05.062468 [debug] [MainThread]: Sending event: {'category':
> 'dbt', 'action': 'package', 'label':
> '5cc0ad0f-792a-49a6-8a66-f59ff8c3e642', 'property_': 'install',
> 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson
> object at 0x000002CDFB6D1EB0>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x000002CDFB6D14C0>]} 14:28:05.063465 [info ] [MainThread]: Installing
> calogica/dbt_expectations 14:28:06.961306 [debug] [MainThread]:
> Sending event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label':
> 'end', 'context':
> [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x000002CDFB689550>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x000002CDFB6D14C0>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x000002CDFB702EE0>]}
>
> ============================== 2022-05-23 14:28:10.424049 | 2a7e240e-1707-4551-8966-58797e038d3a ==============================
> 14:28:10.424049 [info ] [MainThread]: Running with dbt=1.1.0
> 14:28:10.425046 [debug] [MainThread]: running dbt with arguments
> {'write_json': True, 'use_colors': True, 'printer_width': 80,
> 'version_check': True, 'partial_parse': True, 'static_parser': True,
> 'profiles_dir': 'C:\Users\jasonmckenzie\.dbt',
> 'send_anonymous_usage_stats': True, 'event_buffer_size': 100000,
> 'quiet': False, 'no_print': False, 'resource_types': [], 'output':
> 'selector', 'indirect_selection': 'eager', 'which': 'list'}
> 14:28:10.425046 [debug] [MainThread]: Tracking: tracking
> 14:28:10.435018 [debug] [MainThread]: Sending event: {'category':
> 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'start', 'context':
> [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000254727F3D90>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000254727F32E0>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000254727F37C0>]} 14:28:10.462945 [debug] [MainThread]: Sending
> event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'end',
> 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson
> object at 0x00000254727D1820>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000254727D1490>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000254727D19D0>]}
>
> ============================== 2022-05-23 14:28:10.825973 | 8d0ab879-6b59-4473-845a-cde9dd23352b ==============================
> 14:28:10.825973 [info ] [MainThread]: Running with dbt=1.1.0
> 14:28:10.826970 [debug] [MainThread]: running dbt with arguments
> {'write_json': True, 'use_colors': True, 'printer_width': 80,
> 'version_check': True, 'partial_parse': True, 'static_parser': True,
> 'profiles_dir': 'C:\Users\jasonmckenzie\.dbt',
> 'send_anonymous_usage_stats': True, 'event_buffer_size': 100000,
> 'quiet': False, 'no_print': False, 'resource_types': [], 'output':
> 'selector', 'indirect_selection': 'eager', 'which': 'list'}
> 14:28:10.826970 [debug] [MainThread]: Tracking: tracking
> 14:28:10.835946 [debug] [MainThread]: Sending event: {'category':
> 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'start', 'context':
> [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000170D052F100>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000170D052FEB0>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000170D052FC40>]} 14:28:10.892797 [debug] [MainThread]: Sending
> event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'end',
> 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson
> object at 0x00000170D04EC640>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000170D04ECD90>,
> <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at
> 0x00000170D04EC4F0>]}

Comment: when you run `dbt clean` can you confirm that the `dbt_packages` directory is deleted? It seems like there is another process running that is reading from that directory. It's odd (but not impossible) that a restart wouldn't kill that process, but you might have better luck force-deleting that directory natively in your OS, instead of using `dbt clean`

Comment: Yes, the dbt_packages directory is deleted when I run dbt clean.  I force-deleted as well, but the error persists.

Comment: [dbt-expectations](https://github.com/calogica/dbt-expectations/blob/main/packages.yml) depends on dbt-date. Can you remove dbt-date from your packages file and do clean/deps again and see if you still get the error?

Comment: Good thought.  I just tried, but that darn error persists.

Comment: maybe useful to refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70866446/dbt-deps-fails-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process

Comment: And also this issue, could be related: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4372

Comment: Thanks for checking @AleixCC.  I found that Stack thread before I posted and did try to execute dbt deps multiple times, but the outcome was the same.  My directory is on my local drive, so I don't share the same concerns about imaging as Dan.  I'm checking out that github link now which appears to be a good find - thank you.

Comment: The issue seems well documented on github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4372, but no solution.  One person there was able to resolve with multiple executions of dbt deps, but I did that 10 successive times with no change.

Comment: FYI - I overcame this issue by installing dbt into a new directory.  I got a similar error when trying to delete the old directory (Folder In Use - The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program).  This prompted me to install https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer to try to find what was hanging up... I couldn't see anything so I tried deleting the old directory again to see if that helped pinpoint things, but that time I was successful deleting it.  Very strange...

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when trying to install tsql_utils. I 'fixed' it by adding quote marks around the versions.

```
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils 
    version: "0.9.2"
  - package: dbt-msft/tsql_utils
    version: "0.8.1"
```

Initially, I had no quotes around them.

Comment: That's interesting.  I ended up creating a new directory to work from and eventually that lock was released so I could delete the problem directory.  I'm not using quotes in my current packages.yml.